# Angular2: canActivate redirect me to login page even when I'm authenticated

Tags: angular, authentication, angular2-routing

I'm working on a web application with angular2 as frontend and spring/spring security as backend.

Everything works perfectly, the only issue is that even when I'm logged in and I want to refresh a members view, it redirect me to the login page.

**AuthGuard Service**:

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot }    from '@angular/router';
import {LoginService} from './login.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

 constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router) {}


  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let url: string = state.url;

    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }
   checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
    if (this.loginService.isAuthenticated) {  return true; }
      // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
    this.loginService.redirectUrl = url;
    // Navigate to the login page with extras
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

**LoginService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  isAuthenticated: boolean = false;
// store the URL so we can redirect after logging in
  redirectUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    const creds = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password;

    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/webCustomerTracker/login', creds, { headers: headers })
      .map( this.extractData )
     .toPromise()//convert to promise
      .then(//use then instead of subscribe to form promise chain
          success => {
                     if(success) {
                window.localStorage.setItem('auth_key', success.data);
                this.isAuthenticated = true;
                    }
                resolve(this.isAuthenticated);
            });

    }
    );
  }
 logoutAPI(): Observable<any>{
        return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/webCustomerTracker/logout")
                .map( (res: Response) => res.json() )
                .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || ' Server Error '));
 }

   private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body;

    // check if empty, before call json
    if (res.text()) {
        body = res.json();
    }

    return body || {};
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution for this issue, I just did this little change to the **checkLogin** method in the **AuthGuard** service :

```
checkLogin(url: string): boolean {

    if (!!window.localStorage.getItem('auth_key')) {  return true; }
      // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
    this.loginService.redirectUrl = url;
    // Navigate to the login page with extras
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the guard you're making a new instance of the AuthenticationService and

```
this.loginService.isAuthenticated
```

is null. Try using a BehaviourSubject and subscribe to it in order to be able to get the value.

Create a class that has a property of type BehaviorSubject. For example :

```
@Injectable()
export class Globals {
    public loggedUser: BehaviorSubject<Account> = new BehaviorSubject<Account>(null);
```

In this variable you'll store the info for the logged user right after the success of the login request. Storing values is done like this:

```
this.globals.loggedUser.next(--value-to-store--);// should be of type T
```

Then, in order to get the value from this object, inject the class and simply access it like

```
this.globals.loggedUser.getValue()
```

if this is !== null, then you're logged in.

Comment: could you please tell me how to do that  ?? (I'm new to angular2)

Comment: Gave you an example :)